# Magento invalid block type spotlight

Tags: magento

In my exception.log file I have the following messages:

```
2015-04-23T14:43:40+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid blocktype:   
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Spotlight' in /public_html/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): 
Mage::throwException('Invalid blockt...')
#1 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): 
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('page/html_spotl...', Array)
#2 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):   
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('page/html_spotl...', 'spotlight')
#3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):   
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('page/html_spotl...', 'spotlight')
#4 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):  
Mage_Core_Model_Layout- >_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206):   
Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(148): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

I looked at the template files but I couldn't find any file containing or named something with "spotlight" I think it isn't standard Magento. I also believe this error causes the cart page to render incorrectly, is that possible?

Comment: As per code I think error comes on category page not on checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking in the layout files, not the template files. A block with type of `page/html_spotlight` is being added somewhere in the layout. The [extension from this guide](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) can help you with determining where it is getting added.